# Can I set the value of something using Cocoa Bindings based on the value of a segmented control?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have some data stored in an array controller and which is displayed in a table using Cocoa Bindings. There's a text box which displays one of two strings for the selected row, and I want to be able to choose which of them to display using a segmented control. I want it so when the value of the segmented control is changed, the text content of the text box will also change accordingly.

Is there an easy way to do this using cocoa bindings, or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Partially, the `selection` of the array controller can be bound but not the content of label names of the segmented control. You could bind `Selected Label` of the segmented control to a `String` property and use the `didSet` observer to update the text box.

Comment: Do you want to use a segmented control in each row?

Comment: @Willeke no, it's one segmented control at the top of my app. I've got it sorted now, so dw :)